# How do I get the list of Terms not used in any TaxonomyField in a CSOM Console App?

Tags: csom, delete, term

I would like to delete terms not used in a TaxonomyField on any Item in a Document Library.
I am new to CSOM and can't figure out how to proceed on this.

Can you help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the `GetAllTerms` method of the `TermSet` object to retrieve all terms.
2. Use the `GetItems` method of the `List` object to retrieve all items. For each item, you can get the value of the `TaxonomyField` and keep track of the used terms.
3. Any term that is in the list of all terms but not in the list of used terms is a term not used in any `TaxonomyField`.
4. Use the `DeleteObject` method of the `Term` object to delete a term.